# VB 6 Advanced Find Method in View Code

Tags: vb6, find

Lets say i have 3 table A,B,C.
In every table i have some insert query.

I want to using Find "ctrl+f" to find every insert query with some format. 
Example: i want to find code that contain `"insert [table_name] value"` no matter what is the table name (A or B or C), so i want to search some code but skip the word in the middle of it.

I have googling with any keyword, but i doesn't get any solution that even close to what i want.

Is it possible to do something like this.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use what are known as "wildcard" characters.
In the find window, you'll notice there is a check box called "Use Pattern Matching".

If you check this, then you can use some special characters to expand your search.

`?` is a wildcard that indicates any character can take this place. 
`*` is a wildcard that indicates a string of any length could take this place

eg. `ca?` would match `cat, car, cam` etc
`ca*` would match `cat, car, catastrophe, called ...` etc

So something along the lines of `insert * value` should find what you are interested in.